# git rewrite: Does not change author name

Tags: git

The reason I need to rewrite git history is because my name is duplicated and it counts as two developers in the remote.

Also my team recently added a pre-receive hook which rejects unknown author names.

I must fix the problem immediately, so I have followed https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/ and several other guides to try to rewrite authors names from commits.

This is the one I'm using right now:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="tomas.p@mail.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Tomas Prado"
CORRECT_EMAIL="tomas.p@mail.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

**The Problem**

This is a commit that must change

```
commit 355ee6adb0540d3e2eed7163dfe36087f85feb78
Author: tomasp <tomas.p@mail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 6 13:35:25 2016 +0200

    Fix hashed
```

You see, my name should be "Tomas Prado" but it's "tomasp".

After the execution of the github script it stays the same. 
I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `--commit-filter` instead?

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "tomas.p@mail.com" ];
    then
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Tomas Prado";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="tomas.p@mail.com";
            if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "tomas.p@mail.com" ];
            then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Tomas Prado";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="tomas.p@mail.com";
                git commit-tree "$@";
            else
                git commit-tree "$@";
            fi
    else
            if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "tomas.p@mail.com" ];
            then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Tomas Prado";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="tomas.p@mail.com";
                git commit-tree "$@";
            else
                git commit-tree "$@";
            fi
    fi' HEAD
```